# htaccess Redirect - First Segment to PHP File, Second Segment as Parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My htaccess redirect knowledge is somewhat weak, so I was hoping to get some help here.

I currently have the following redirect, which works well:

```
# remove trailing slash
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# redirect to clean URL
RewriteCond /%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]+)$ /$1.php
```

This takes a URL like `www.mysite.com/about` to `www.mysite.com/about.php`

Now I would like to keep this behavior, but add parameters (if applicable), as such:

`www.mysite.com/about` => `www.mysite.com/about.php`

`www.mysite.com/gallery/1` => `www.mysite.com/gallery.php?id=1`

If possible, I might like to expand this system to 2 or more parameters, as such:

`www.mysite.com/gallery/1/2` => `www.mysite.com/gallery.php?id=1&section=2`

So the pattern would be:

- First URL segment redirects to a PHP file
- (Optionally) the second segment gets added as the `id` parameter
- (Optionally) the third segment gets added as the `section` parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it a try

```
# remove trailing slash
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# redirect to clean URL
RewriteCond /%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]+)$ /$1.php
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]+)$ /$1.php?id=$2&section=$3

#RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]+)$ /$1.php?param1=$2&param2=$3&param3=$4 and so on
```

Comment: This works well for a URL like `www.mysite.com/gallery/1/2`, but does not work for `www.mysite.com/about` (because it doesn't have the other two slashes, I suppose).

Comment: @Steve see my updated answer you have to redefine the rule again

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using a generic router. This completely liberates your redirects to use whatever you want.

Typically a router rule looks like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ handler.php?path=$1 [QSA]
```

You can add the `-f` and `-d` if you like to avoid sending static files (like CSS files and images) through your router, but in my case, even those pass through my router.

Then in `handler.php` you check the input, see if it's something you know how to deal with, like: is the URL like `/about` or is it like `/gallery/[0-9]`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The site I am working on right now is very small in scope, so in this case it is easier for me to add the few redirect rules.  But I will keep this in mind for future uses.